# De-Serialize multiple BSon ObjectID to String of a MongoDB document in C# .Net

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, deserialization, bson

I need to de-serialize the Value of **_id** and **Boss_id** from **`ObjectId`** to **`string`** for all document in a mongodb collection using C# .Net

My Collection **`Employee`** is (Here I pasted only 2 Documents, in real I'm having more than 10K Documents)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575845a713d284da0ac2ee81"),
    "Boss_id" : ObjectId("575841b313d284da0ac2ee7d"),
    "Emp_Name" : "Raj",
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575845d213d284da0ac2ee82"),
    "Boss_id" : ObjectId("575841b313d284da0ac2ee7d"),
    "Emp_Name" : "Kumar"
}
```

My C# Source - Model Class **`EmployeeModel`**

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Boss_Id { get; set; }

    public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
}
```

My C# MongoDB Code:

```
private static IMongoClient _client;
private static IMongoDatabase _database;

_client = new MongoClient();
_database = _client.GetDatabase("RMS");
var collection = _database.GetCollection<EmployeeModel>("Employee");

BsonDocument temp = new BsonDocument("Emp_Name", "Raj");
var cItem = collection.Find(temp).ToList();

if ((cItem != null) && (cItem.Count > 0))
{
    _EmpList = cItem;
}
```

> Its throwing Exception
>
> Attributes of type
>   MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes.BsonIdAttribute can only be
>   applied to a single member.

kindly assist me how to fetch the documents ?

Comment: I think the error tries to tell you that you can't use 2 fields as your BsonType.ObjectId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below. [BsonId] is the id of the document so in the Json it's the "_id" element. That's all it identifiies

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }


    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Boss_Id { get; set; }

    public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes. You are Correct. Thanks.